# openid Authentication for multi domain website

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

we have a website hosted in IIS, we have pointed the multiple domains to the same website.
like

```
www.exmple.com
www.example.in
www.wxaple.co.uk
```

and so on. 
similarly, we have pointed more than 30 domains to this website.

Before there was no authentication on this website, now we need to implement authentication. so we have used OpenID connect and Azure AD for authentication.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-protocols-openid-connect-code

This is working fine for one domain because we can configure the redirection URL for 1 domain. But how we can make sure this will work fine for all domains.
or any other approach to implementing this.

Answer (score 0):

Though you have many domains in a website, **when you login in your website the appId is the same**. So, you could use the access token to request your domain website.

BTW, you need to add your domain into your `Redirect Uri` in App registered in your Azure AD.

[image]